# taking picture make the app crash

Tags: android, android-camera

I have developed an android app on android studio.
I was using LG G5 and everything worked fine. I just moved to samsung s8 and when im tring to open the camera through the app, it crashes.
I have try to debug this and i found that the app crashes at:
looper.java in funcation loop().
How can it be fixed?

this is the error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.imperialsoupgmail.tesseractexample, PID: 26176
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6891)
                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26083)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6891) 
                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26083) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374) 
               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: file
                  at android.net.Uri.fromFile(Uri.java:453)
                  at com.imperialsoupgmail.tesseractexample.MainActivity.takePicture(MainActivity.java:258)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6891) 
                  at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:12651) 
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:26083) 
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: post your complete error

Comment: post your error logs

Comment: Samsung phones' cameras does cause this problem, try checking for all available modes of camera before calling / using the camera.

Answer (score 1):

> Hai Mizrachi, this error happens from android os version, so please
>   follow the below code :

**First Check your Mobile OS version in the below code:** `

```
private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo", "Cancel"};
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyProfileNew.this);
        builder.setTitle("Select Profile Image");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                boolean result = checkPermission(MyProfileNew.this);
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    userChoosenTask = "Take Photo";
                    if (result)


                        Log.v("current Version", String.valueOf(currentapiVersion));
                        Log.v("Bulid Version", String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.N));

                        if (currentapiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                            // Do something for lollipop and above versions
                            Log.v("current Version", String.valueOf(currentapiVersion));
                            Log.v("Bulid Version", String.valueOf(Build.VERSION_CODES.N));
                            Log.v("OS Version","N+");
                            startCamera();
                        } else {
                            Log.v("OS Version","N-");
                            captureImage();
                        }

                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

**If OS version is less than N means the code is below:**

```
 private void startCamera() {
        try {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() throws IOException {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                return;
            }
            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                //Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile(createImageFile());
                Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(MyProfileNew.this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", createImageFile());
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
            }
        }
    }
```

**If OS version is greater than N means the code is below:**

```
 //capture image from the camera
    private void captureImage() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        // start the image capture Intent
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
        System.out.println("Camera File URI"+fileUri);
    }
```

This above code is 100% working for me, try this code.

Answer (score 0):

Below sample you can try, it worked for me to some extent. It's a quite old code.

```
List<String> supportedFocusModes = cameraParameters.getSupportedFocusModes();

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH &&
           supportedFocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO)) {
    cameraParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO);
} else if (supportedFocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE)) {
    cameraParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE);
} else if (supportedFocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO)) {
    cameraParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_MACRO);
} else if (supportedFocusModes.contains(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO)) {
    // auto focus on request only
    cameraParameters.setFocusMode(Camera.Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
}
mCamera.setParameters(cameraParameters);
```

Comment: where did you put this code?

Comment: @GuyMizrachi show the code part where app is crashing.

Comment: @GuyMizrachi u can use it inside the open Camera method, or basically, anywhere, where you are check for camera null condition, or trying open camera, or accessing parameters.